# Can no longer load or run R/ RStudio on Mac.

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

8GB RAM, 350 GB of flash storage space available.  MacBook is 3 years old.

I have had an enjoyable month, starting at the bottom of the R and RStudio learning curves.

But today, for the first time, bang, mostly dead.

I have suspected some sort of problem for 2-3 weeks, because Save Image and Open have been taking a LONG time.  But I have not known of anything to do.

QUESTION:

Are there known conflicts with other applications on a Mac?

Is there another question I should be asking?

The Genius at our local Apple store could not help.

After detecting R/Studio failure, but before I went to the store, earlier today I upgraded to current versions of MacOS, Apple Pages, Apple Numbers, Apple Keynote, Lemke Graphics Converter, Slack, and Kindle.

I have rebooted ~6 times.  I have download R from Berkeley, and RStudio ~6 times each, and gotten no messages about installation problems.

But, ~15 seconds after I launch R (directly, not via RStudio), the pizza of death starts spinning.

Surprisingly, 2-3 minutes later, the pizza goes away, and I get the R console.

I have tested it only with gc(), which works.

I click Quit R, it asks if I want to save the image.  When I say Save, the rotating starburst (not the pizza) appears, and hangs totally.  I Force Quit.

When I launch RStudio,  a couple of minutes go by with the rotating starburst.  I get a message saying that R is taking a long time, and do I want to keep waiting or quit the effort.

When I pick Quit, it hangs again for 1+ minutes, so I Force Quit.

:-((

Jeb
Palo Alto, CA

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your workspace image somehow got corrupted.

Have you tried deleting the `.RData` file, and then re-starting RStudio?